# Cropping 2048x1152 (16:9) to 1.85:1 removing black bars

Tags: ffmpeg

for the past 48 hours I tried to crop the black bars of a 2048x1152 (16:9) video to a 1.85:1 aspect ratio (which is 2048x1107) so that the encoded video shows exactly what is meant to be.

First problem:
2048x1107 (1.85:1) is not common but is it basically possible to create?
Can i encode with libx264 with an odd number value like 1107?

Second problem:
If not, how can I make a crop & resize encode in one sitting?
Means...
Cropping 2048x1152 (16:9) to 2048x1107 (1.85) AND resizing the 2048x1107 (1.85, uncommon) to 1998x1080  (2K DCP FLAT)

I only manage to get a 1998x1080 (1.85:1) with too much cropped on all sides... :/

Thanks for you help, guys!

Comment: Duplicate (crossreference): https://superuser.com/questions/810471/remove-mp4-video-top-and-bottom-black-bars-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Duplicates only apply if the other Q is on the same site.

Comment: I haven't flagged it as a duplicate, I just put the duplicate from superuser there. This is the reason I added the "crossreference"...

Answer (score 1):

You can carry out the changes in one command by chaining the respective filters.

Basic syntax is

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "crop=2048:1107:exact=1,scale=1998:1080,setsar=1" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: As stated in my other comment, to get the exact cropping values, look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/810471/remove-mp4-video-top-and-bottom-black-bars-using-ffmpeg